Exploratory Factor analyses on large data sets
I have a question about using EFA on a large data set of survey questions. The goal is to form an index from over 200 items, and partly also as a form of dimension reduction (i understand PCA is also useful here). However when I performed EFA with such a large array of items, natrually i get almost 40  factors, along with probably 100+ items with loadings of less than 0.3. My question is, what should i do next? Do I need to remve those 100 items one by one and then run the EFA again 100 times? Also, it depends which items i remove first right? Can someone please help? If you can think of a more approproiate method please sugget it as well.

Please say more about your goal. What do you mean by an "index"?

A legitimate answer would need to come out of extensive readings or in-depth coaching.  But a short cut such as this may help:  https://yellowbrickstats.com/documents/Factor%20Analysis%20Decision%20Guide.pdf
